# A not wanted diagonal arrow is appearing in the diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I don't want the diagonal arrow appearing in the second line. Can someone please help me to fix it? Here's the tex code I used:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathbb{C}\arrow[rrrr,"\times e'_\lambda(z)",bend left=18] \arrow[d,equal] & 
(\pi^*\tau_\mu^*L)_z \arrow[l] \arrow[r,equal] \arrow[d,equal]& 
(\tau_\mu^*L)_{\pi(z)}\arrow[r,equal] \arrow[d,equal]& 
(\pi^*\tau_\mu^*L)_{z+\lambda}\arrow[r] \arrow[d,equal] &\mathbb{C} 
\arrow[d,equal]\\
\mathbb{C}\arrow[rrrr,"\times e_\lambda(z+\mu)",bend right=18] 
\arrow[d,equal] &(\pi^*L)_{z+\mu} \arrow[l] \arrow[r,equal]& 
L_{\pi(z+\mu)}\arrow[r,equal]& (\pi^*L)_{z+\mu+\lambda}\arrow[r]&\mathbb{C} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the `\arrow[d,equal]`s is the culprit.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
    \mathbb{C}                          \arrow[rrrr, "\times e'_\lambda(z)", bend left=18] \arrow[d, equal]
    & (\pi^*\tau_\mu^*L)_z              \arrow[l] \arrow[r, equal] \arrow[d,equal]
    & (\tau_\mu^*L)_{\pi(z)}            \arrow[r, equal] \arrow[d, equal]
    & (\pi^*\tau_\mu^*L)_{z+\lambda}    \arrow[r] \arrow[d, equal]
    & \mathbb{C}                        \arrow[d, equal] \\
    \mathbb{C}                          \arrow[rrrr, "\times e_\lambda(z+\mu)", bend right=18] % \arrow[d,equal]
    & (\pi^*L)_{z+\mu}                  \arrow[l] \arrow[r, equal]
    & L_{\pi(z+\mu)}                    \arrow[r, equal]
    & (\pi^*L)_{z+\mu+\lambda}          \arrow[r]
    & \mathbb{C} 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.